# Redefinition of as a different kind of symbol

Tags: c++

I'm creating a simple C++ header file in my xcode ios project but getting error "Redifinition of 'foo' as a different kind of symbol".

Here's the code

```
class foo 
{
    public:
         char* getLabel(char* params);
};
```

Comment: :)) Are you re-defining foo? Still get the error if you change the name?

Comment: Search for `foo` and see what else it represents in your system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty self-explanatory, `foo` is already defined in the same namespace, and you are trying to re-define it.

The part "as a different kind of symbol" suggests that the existing `foo` is something else rather than a class definition. Changing the name will most likely solve your issue. Another way would be to put your definition of `foo` into another namespace. And anyway I would not recommend you to name something as `foo` in a *real* project, no matter how small it is ;)